# Streaming Filestream video data into JW Player in asp.net

Tags: filestream, jwplayer

I am working with Filestream in sql server 2008 to store image and video files from an asp.net web app. I am able to upload some image and video files so far and store them in the Filestream-enabled sql server database.

But when I want to display both the image and video files back to my application. I am able to get the image files and display them in the application. But I am not able to retrieve back the video files and play them in a JW Player from my application.

So far, I have done the following: I have an .aspx web form with a gridview control. In the code-behind for this web form, I have binded data for the gridview control as follows:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["tmmaConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID, ProgramTitle,ProgramVideoName, ProgramId from [tblProgramContent] where programId="+progId, connection);
        SqlDataAdapter ada = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        ada.Fill(dt);
        GVVideos.DataSource = dt;
        GVVideos.DataBind();
```

My gridview control looks the following

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GVVideos" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
                 <asp:BoundField HeaderText = "Program File Name" DataField="ProgramVideoName" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText = "Program Title" DataField="ProgramTitle" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Program Video">
                <ItemTemplate>
                     <!--<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%= "GetProgram.ashx?prog-Id="+ Eval("ProgramId") %>'/>
                      <asp:LinkButton ID="lbGetFile" runat="server" CommandName="GetFile" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ProgramId") %>' ><img src='<%#Eval("ProgramId") %>.jpg' /></asp:LinkButton>-->
                   <div id="play-video" >
                      <a href="" id="play-prog">  <%#Eval("ProgramVideoName") %> </a>
                      <embed
                            flashvars="file=<%# "GetProgram.ashx?prog-Id="+ Eval("ProgramId") %> "
                            allowfullscreen="true"
                            allowscripaccess="always"
                            id="player1"
                            name="player1"
                            src="Scripts/jwplayer/player.swf"
                            width="200"
                            height="180"
                        /> 
                        </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

I have passed the `<%# "GetProgram.ashx?prog-Id="+ Eval("ProgramId") %>` HTTP handler that takes the program-id and then return the corresponding video file back to the client. But this doesn't return the video file and embed it in the JW player. 
Is there any better way to do this or what modifications should I do to the above sample program?

Comment: Any one with idea please. I am a bit stuck here.

Comment: Did you come to any solution? I am very interested in this problem, too!